# How skip reading " : " while taking input from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file

Lets say I want to input the hours, minutes and seconds from the first line of a file and store them to 3 different variables, hrs, mins and sec respectively.
I cant figure out an easy way to skip reading the colon character (":").

Input file example:

12:49:00

Store:

```
hrs = 12
mins = 59
sec = 00
```

Comment: Maybe use [boost::tokenizer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/tokenizer/doc/index.html)

Comment: Hello sir, welcome to the community.  While you are asking for help with the problem you face. We need more information before anyone truly jumps on your question with an answer.  What have you tried and what hasn't worked? Do you have any code that we can see?  Otherwise your question is at risk for being closed.

Comment: You could use [std::get_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)

Comment: You can use `std:getline` with the delimitor `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative not using a temporary character for skipping the colon:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        int h,m,s;
        std::cin >> h;
        std::cin.ignore(1) >> m;
        std::cin.ignore(1) >> s;
        std::cout << h << ':' << m << ':' << s << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were quite helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::regex` to match, range-check and validate your input all at once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::regex time_regex("(\\d|[0,1]\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\\d):([0-5]\\d)");
    std::smatch time_match;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if (std::regex_match(line, time_match, time_regex))
        {
            int hours = std::stoi(time_match[1]);
            int minutes = std::stoi(time_match[2]);
            int seconds = std::stoi(time_match[3]);
            std::cout << "h=" << hours << " m=" << minutes << " s=" << seconds << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid time: " << line << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See this example live [here](https://ideone.com/W93FTC).

Breaking down the regular expression `(\\d|[0,1]\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\\d):([0-5]\\d)`:

1. `\d|[0,1]\d|2[0-3]` matches the hour (24-hour time) which is one of:

   - `\d` : 0-9
   - `[0,1]\d` : 01-19
   - `2[0-3]` : 20-23
2. `[0-5]\d` matches the minutes: two digits 00-59
3. `[0-5]\d` matches the seconds: two digits 00-59, as above.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Ill look into it!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
int h, m, s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
char c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
cin >> h >> c >> m >> c >> s;
```

You just skip `:` symbol this way. I don't know whether it's a good solution.

With `cin.ignore`:

```
cin >> h;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
cin.ignore(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
cin >> m;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
cin.ignore(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
cin >> s;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Although is a viable solution, it's not that efficient. Why would I use an extra variable?

Comment: Why it's not efficient? Additional variable has almost zero influence on performance. The variable is needed for reading `:`. I.e., you've read `h` and then you want to skip one symbol. The easiest way (I know about) to skip it is to read it. For this you create a `char` variable and read a symbol into this variable.

Comment: @AnthonyKpS Use `cin.ignore` instead of input to variable `c`, although it still does the same. Taking a character out of a stream that is having the same character type for `charT` in the underlying `basic_streambuf` is basically the fastest thing you can do on a stream.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Comment: How?  @GézaTörök

Comment: Thanks! Ill look into it. @GézaTörök

Comment: The think is i wanna stick to the cin command. How can i use cin.ignore() while using cin << ...

Comment: `cin` is not a command: it's a class.  Part of this answer uses `std::cin::operator>>`, and part uses `std::cin::ignore`.

Comment: @paddy `cin` is not a class, but a static object of `std::istream`, or of some descendant type of that, depending on the implementation. Read:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin

Comment: @GézaTörök yeah, I meant that but wrote my comment in a hurry and was too late to edit when I realized I need to use more precise language.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

There are already several good answers and one that has already been accepted; however I like to propose my solution not only as a valid answer to your problem but also in regards to a good design practice. IMHO when it involves reading information from a file and storing it's contents to variables or data structures I prefer to do it in a specific way. I like to separate the functionality and responsibility of specific operations into their own functions:

---

> - **1:** I first like to have a function to open a file, read the contents and to store the information into either a string, a stream or some large buffer. Once the appropriate amount of information is read from the file, then the function will close the file handle as we are done with it and then return back the results. There are several ways to do this yet they are all similar.
>
>   - **a:** Read a single line from the file and return back a string or a stream.
>   - **b:** Read in all information form the file line by line and store each line into its own string or stream and return back a vector of those strings or streams.
>   - **c:** Read in all of the contents of the file into a single string, stream or large buffer and return that back.
> - **2:** After I have the contents of that file then I will typically call a function that will parse that data and these functions will vary depending on the type of content that needs to be parsed based on the data structures that will be used. Also, these parsing functions will call a function that will split the string into a vector of strings called tokens. After the split string function is called then the parsing of data will use the string manipulators-converters to convert a string to the required built in types that are needed for the current data structure that is in use and store them into the data structure that is passed in by reference.
> - **3:** There are two variations of my splitString function.
>
>   - **a:** One takes a single character as a delimiter.
>   - **b:** The other will take a string as its delimiter.
>   - **c:** Both functions will return a vector of strings, based on the delimiter used.

---

Here is an example of my code using this text file for input.

*time.txt*

```
4:32:52
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

struct Time {
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& s, char delimiter ) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream( s );
    while( std::getline( tokenStream, token, delimiter ) ) {
        tokens.push_back( token );
    }

    return tokens;
}

std::string getLineFromFile( const char* filename ) {
    std::ifstream file( filename );
    if( !file ) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error( stream.str() );
    }

    std::string line;
    std::getline( file, line );

    file.close();

    return line;
}

void parseLine( const std::string& fileContents, Time& time ) {
    std::vector<std::string> output = splitString( fileContents, ':' );

    // This is where you would want to do your sanity check to make sure
    // that the contents from the file are valid inputs before converting
    // them to the appropriate types and storing them into your data structure.

    time.hours = std::stoi( output.at( 0 ) );
    time.minutes = std::stoi( output.at( 1 ) );
    time.seconds = std::stoi( output.at( 2 ) );
}

int main() {
    try {
        Time t;
        std::string line = getLineFromFile( "time.txt" );
        parseLine( line, t );

        std::cout << "Hours: " << t.hours << '\n'
            << "Minutes: " << t.minutes << '\n'
            << "Seconds: " << t.seconds << "\n\n";

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Output:*

```
Hours: 4
Minutes: 32
Seconds: 52
```

---

Now as you can see in this particular situation the functions that are being used here is designed only to read a single line from the file and of course the very first line from the file. I have other functions in my library not shown here that will read each line of a file until there are no more lines to read, or read all of the file into a single buffer. I have another version of split string that will take a string as its delimiter instead of a single character. Finally for the parsing function, each parsing function will end up being unique due to the fact that it will rely on the data structure that you are trying to use.

This allows the code to be readable as each function does what it is supposed to do and nothing more. I prefer this design over the fact of trying to get information from a file and trying to parse it while the file is open. Too many things can go wrong while the file is open and if the data is read wrong or corrupted but to the point where the compiler doesn't complain about it, then your variables or data structures may contain invalid information without you being aware of it. At least in this way you can open the file, get what you need from the file and store it into a string or a vector of strings, close the file when done reading and return back the contents. Then it becomes the parsing function's responsibility to test the data after it has been tokenized. Now, in the current parsing function that I shown above I did not do any sanity check to keep things simple, but that is where you would test your data to see if the information is valid before returning back your populated data structure.

---

*If you are interested in another version of this where there are multiple lines being read in from the file, just comment a request and I will append it to this answer.*

---

Comment: This will happily parse `+999:-1-bottles:0f::beer` as a time.

Comment: @paddy If you read towards the bottom; I mentioned the fact that the parsing function would be responsible to check if the data is valid although I didn't incorporate it into the shown code. I tried to keep it as basic and simple as possible. The OP should be able to add the functionality to check for valid input. I was just giving them a basic framework on how to parse data from an input file along with how to use a delimiter to skip over unwanted character(s) by breaking the problem down into separate functions. I can add a comment into that function that mentions this.